# Dealing with Encrypted files across multiple programs to ensure security and secrecy of data

Tags: security, encryption

I have the following situation and need some suggestions.
I have 3 programs A, B, and C
I have a file written in a certain format and it is encrypted.
Program A can decrypt the file, program B converts the file format to another required format, and program C encrypts the output file from B.
Now the suggested flow for this behavior was to decrypt the file and write it to desk, then convert it with B writing the output to disk, then encrypting it using C.
But this is not secure since some one could look up the file when it is still not encrypted after step B.
How can we deal with this situation to ensure the security and secrecy of data in that file?

Comment: Communicate over a secured sockets without ever storing it.

Comment: How can i do that if both A and C are in C++ and B is in another language ?
Sorry if the question is not good enough but i am not familiar with secure sockets

Comment: Socket communication is independent of the programming language. TCP communication underlines the whole of the world wide web.

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question that deals with workflow more than software code itself, so I'll offer some high-level info.

You are correct that you should NEVER write decrypted data to disk if at all possible. There are almost always better ways to handle such workflows, and the restrictions that prevent it should be worked around in other ways.

For example, it is generally best for a single application to handle functions of A, B, and C, instead of separate applications. This allows you to use secure memory to handle the functions so you're not writing out decrypted data.

If that isn't possible due to outside requirements/restrictions, then you can consider options (like others have mentioned) such as using secure socket-based communication between different application processes. This presumes that each application is running/listening on a socket so they can communicate securely, so if that's not true you need a different method. Are you writing apps A, B, and C, or did someone else create them?  For this to work, application A connects to B over a secure socket, calls a function *(such as "convert" in your case)*, and then sends a data stream of the data to be converted.

If you cannot use secure sockets, or if the machines are on different systems without inter-process communications, you'll need a secure transport layer so the apps can stream the file back and forth securely. This can be done using TLS and other methods with different formats of encoding the data.  I assume in your example they're on the same machine since they're all able to see the same file(s), so this last point probably doesn't apply to you.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer
I have access to A and C's code but can not modify B i call it using system command.
So can I establish this secure connection between A and B and B and C?

Comment: The only way to know that is by researching whether B has any such interfaces. You'll have to check the developer documentation for B, or perhaps the man/info pages depending on what it is.